# Epson XP-205 printer driver failed After Ubuntu 18.04 Update

Tags: epson

The printer was working fine on Ubuntu 16.04 until I updated the system to 18.04.  Ever since the system can't see the printer.  Can you please point me to where I can get an updated driver and how to install it.  This only seems to have effected the printer as the scanner works fine.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Google "epson drivers for linux" should get you what you need.  It pointed me to this page: https://epson.com/Support/wa00821 There you will find both drivers to download as well as documentation.

I noticed that there are recent driver updates for your XP-205 printer.

I also found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/401119/should-i-set-up-my-cups-printing-to-use-ipp-lpd-or-url) answer informative.

If it is a networked printer, make sure you don't have a firewall or vpn that may be preventing your computer from seeing other devices on your LAN.