# My computer "rediscover" my HP Printer over and over again... and duplicates the entry. Anything I can do to avoid that?

Tags: networking, printing, hp

I got a new printer as the old one (16 years old!) did not want to print anything anymore. Bizarre since it printed just fine and all of a sudden, just blank pages.

Anyway, the new printer is on the network. All I had to do is plug it in, enter its MAC address in my DHCP server to force a given IP (I like doing so for security since that way I can easily block traffic from the printer if I want to). It prints and scans like a charm.

However, once in a while my Linux Ubuntu 18.04 tells me: "Hey man! I found a printer!" and it adds the printer to the list again and again. It's not a constant message, it happens once or twice a day. But it's still weird since I already have it in my list and that entry works as expected when printing... (for scanning I use the HTTP interface, so no special entry here.)

I'm thinking this may be a bug, but maybe someone else ran in this problem and knows how to circumvent the issue as of now. Anyone?

Example of what I see in the preferences:

[image]

---

Update: if that helps, I have these two entries from `/var/log/cups/error_log`:

```
W [29/Mar/2020:21:30:52 -0700] CreateProfile failed: org.freedesktop.ColorManager.AlreadyExists:profile id \'HP_Color_LaserJet_Pro_M478f_9f_117A48_@HPF8B46A117A48.local-Gray..\' already exists
W [29/Mar/2020:21:30:52 -0700] CreateProfile failed: org.freedesktop.ColorManager.AlreadyExists:profile id \'HP_Color_LaserJet_Pro_M478f_9f_117A48_@HPF8B46A117A48.local-DeviceN..\' already exists
```

Comment: Right, I don't know whether that's a bug or something I'm doing wrong...

Comment: It may be a bug in IPP. See more [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/401119/should-i-set-up-my-cups-printing-to-use-ipp-lpd-or-url)

Comment: See this also: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1826159 I got it in 20.04 but seemed like duplicate entry for IPv4 & IPv6 causing issues.

Comment: @oldfred I don't see any crash in my syslog. The cups log only have some errors about duplication.

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal and go to:

```
/etc/cups/cups-browsed.conf
```

Then make the following change in the file:

```
BrowseRemoteProtocols none
```

save and then restart CUPS:

```
service cups restart
```

Comment: I would imagine that the detection with the explicit "Add Printer" button would still work even if that option is set to `none`? I read the [docs](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/cups-browsed/cups-browsed.conf.5.en.html) but can't comprehend what really happens there...

Comment: Yes, t should still work using Add Printer.

Comment: Okay, I wanted to check after a reboot, just in case the restart wasn't enough. Note that since 16.04, you are expected to use `systemctl restart cups`. Anyway... it didn't work. I still see the second instance of the printer appearing.

Comment: Note that I also tried with `BrowseLocalProtocols none` and it did not help either.